# django: cant import models from global app

Tags: python, django, import, models

Trying to import models from different app in views.py:

```
from global.models import Global
```

Console raise an error:

```
    from global.models import Global
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked a lot of information, but cant find what iam doing wrong.

global.models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Global(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Глобальные настройки'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Глобальные настройки'

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Глобальные настройки'
```

projects.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from global.models import Global
from .models import Advertising, Films, Presentations, AuthorsLeft, AuthorsRight, BackstageImg
from django.utils import timezone
```

in my editor 'global' has blue color, and if i try to import another app it works normally. Could it be that 'global' reserved by django, or i simply doing something wrong?

Comment: `global` is a keyword in python .

Comment: So i cant do anything without renaming an app?

Comment: Yes, you can't use that name

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
global_model = get_model('global', 'Global')
```

You can use it, like this:

```
first_instance = global_model.objects.first()
print("Phone: {}".format(first_instance.phone))
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, but i already renamed everything :)